# Why does java force me to add f when I use float?

Tags: java

I'm very new to programming. I have the following code:

```
float f = 18.45f;
```

this works fine. If I change that to:

```
float f = 18.45;
```

java saying this as error:

```
error: possible loss of precision
```

But its optional in terms of `double`. But in `long` again I'm facing the same problem.

Why does java forces me to do so, but not in case with `double`?

Comment: `double` is the default type for floating point numbers. `18.45` is implicitly a `double`

Comment: A greater issue is why are you even using a float when double is better since it is more precise (as Java is warning you about)? The only time I use a float is when a method parameter requires float for a proper overload.

Comment: This is so that people won't come so often to Stack Overflow to ask why float multiplication is broken in Java.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes that's what `BigDecimal` is for. Still, it's a good one, +1 :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In Java, `18.45` is a `double` data type which holds 64-bit. `float` data type can hold up to 32-bit only. Adding the extra `f` makes it a float (float literal).

See [Primitive Data Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) for more details.

Comment: What's really surprising is not the number of up-votes but the fact this is the only answer. I mean, what are the odds? It usually takes a dozen of identical posts to answer a question like this.

Comment: SO even `long` is `double` by default?

Comment: @Tom Usually here in SO, the answer with highest-rep gets more up-votes while the others don't.

Comment: @sriram `long` is an integer number (such as `12L`), while `double` is a floating-point number (such as `12.34`). Also note that `12` is `int` not `long`.

Comment: @Eng.Fouad you're slowly but inevitably snowballing into a Jon Skeet